# Angular 7 httpClient.post subscribe data is not accessible in the angular template

Tags: angular, angular7

Tech: Angular 7

I am trying to subscribe to httpClient.post and in the *subscribe* I am assigning the response to my local model and that local model is being used in the Angular HTML template to display the server response values

In the HTML template the model attributes are empty and are not displaying the assigned server response after *subscribe*.

However, in the console inside the subscribe I am able to print the model values

My code snippet for controller:

```
constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){
this.mymodel = new MyModel();
}

onSubmit() {
this.submitted = true;
// this.mymodel.success  = false; //this.mymodel is my model object
if (this.form.invalid) { //reactive form
  return;
} else {
 const result: model= Object.assign({}, this.form.value);
this.httpClient.post<MyModel>('http://myservice/url/api', result)
.subscribe(
  response => {  this.mymodel = response;
  console.log(this.mymodel.firstname) //this is printing the server response value 
  }
  );
}
```

}

My code snippet for template (HTML):

```
<body>
<p>{{mymodel.firstname}}</p>
<p>{{mymodel.lastname}}</p>
```

Note: The same code is working perfectly in Angular 5.

What am I doing wrong here, what is the missing in my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: Edited, previously I didn't added {{ in the template.

Comment: There is a difference between `firstname` and `firstName`

Comment: its an typo error in the question. now I updated.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
<p>{{mymodel?.firstName}}</p> <!--{{mymodel?.firstname}}-->
<p>{{mymodel?.lastName}}</p>
```

- You are not binding the values to what's declared in your  TS part
- Check your model , whether it is `firstname` or `firstName`, could not be both.
- Separe your services from components, create other injectable classes (services = classes with `@Injectable()`) and inject them in your components **WHERE** you should subscribe on them once inner methods are called.

Comment: I edited my question. I wrongly gave the declared values in the above question.      Do you think is there any relation with the reactive forms I am using, because in the template I have a form which is angular reactive form and I am doing validations on that  reactive form?

Comment: @user3854185 , try `<p>{{mymodel | json}}</p>` , tell me what gives u ?

Comment: It is giving me the model json object in the which is in my model. For instance my model has following attributes.
         {
  "data": {},
  "notifications": {
    "errors": [],
    "warnings": []
  }
}

Comment: I even tried with Elvis operator "?" but no luck. my service response is slower is it causing the html to load first and the binding is not happening after the load?

Comment: @user3854185, then there is a problem there, `<p>{{mymodel | json}}</p>` should return your object where u can find `firstname`, i do not see it there, maybe in `data` ?

Comment: Fixed the model. I still have the issue. I guess there is some problem with my subscribe or model initialization.